# Oracle Procedure- Select all tables and then loop though the records of those tables

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I got all the tables from my database that starts with "FULLTEXTLOOKTABLE_%"
Now i want to loop though all those tables.
Select each record from those tables and store the data in 4 variables.
Then delete that particular row in table
Insert into table using the data in those 4 variable.

I want to do this because there was a mismatch in the insertion of data in columns, i cannot alter the column name so i have to truncate the table re-insert correctly.

The code i wrote till now is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "Update"(name_in IN varchar2 )
AS 
  iID       NUMBER(10,0); 
  FullTextDetails     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE); 
  Regex VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE); 
  MinMatch   NUMBER(10,0); 
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'FULLTEXTLOOKTABLE_%' )
  LOOP
    // Loop Throgh all records of c.table_name
    // insert the data into iID, FullTextDetails,Regex,MinMatch
    //Delete that row 
    //Insert it again using the data in variables
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: do you want to insert data in new table or in same table?

Comment: same table @Paras

Comment: What's the point in deleting a row and then inserting the same row again? That could be done much more efficiently by simply doing nothing.

Comment: Can you please clarify on "there was a mismatch..." to help us understand your task? Especially why is truncating the table helping with the column names?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing record by record, you can do it at a table level.

Create a new table tab_dest having the same structure as the source table tab_src including data as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_DEST AS
SELECT * FROM TAB_SRC;
```

Truncate your source table as -

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TAB_SRC;
```

Insert the records from TAB_DEST back to TAB_SRC specifying the column order -

```
INSERT INTO TAB_SRC(COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT COL1, COL3 AS COL2, COL2 AS COL3
FROM TAB_DEST;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks shrek, But i want to do it in a procedure, because creating a table requires privileges(admin rights)

Comment: @HariKrishnan: Creating a table doesn't need admin rights, the privilege `CREATE TABLE` is sufficient. You alread have the privilege `CREATE PROCEDURE`, because you can create this procedure. In my experience, they are usually bundled together.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this but for this way, you need to create a procedure that returns reference cursor

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "Update"(name_in IN varchar2 )
AS 
  iID       NUMBER(10,0); 
  FullTextDetails     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE); 
  Regex VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE); 
  MinMatch   NUMBER(10,0); 
  TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
  tmp_cursor cur_type;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'FULLTEXTLOOKTABLE_%' )
  LOOP
    tmp_cursor := prc_that_returns_ref_cursor(table_name);
    //Delete the data from table
    FOR tmp_cursor_rec IN tmp_cursor LOOP
        //Insert it again using the data in tmp_cursor_rec.column name
    END LOOP;
END;
```